# Error received at "Event = resultSet(3)"

Tags: vbscript, qtp

Unable to figure out the syntax error in the line "Event = resultSet(3)"

Function Run_Test_Flow(str_TestCaseID, str_flowTable_Name)

```
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Persist Security Info=False; data source=C:\Datasource\DataBase.accdb"
con.Open
sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & str_flowTable_Name & " WHERE TC_Name = '" & str_TestCaseID & "'"

Set resultSet = con.Execute (sqlQuery)

While Not resultSet.EOF
    MsgBox(resultSet(3))
    Event = resultSet(3)

    Object = Split(CStr(resultSet(4)),",")

    Eval(Event & "(Object)")

    resultSet.MoveNext()
Wend
```

End Function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**'Event' is a reserved keyword in VBScript.** You can not use it as a variable.